# How to migrate multilingual content from CSV to Drupal 8?

Tags: 8, migrations, importing-exporting

I come from read [Using the new Drupal 8 Migration API / Module](https://blog.liip.ch/archive/2016/05/04/using-the-new-drupal-8-migration-api-module.html) and [Content Migration: CSV to Drupal 8](http://browarddrupal.org/PastMeetings/february-2016) the process to create a migration is very clear and its works, but I can't find how to migrate content to a Multilingual site. In the [Migrate API overview](https://www.drupal.org/node/2127611) I can't find any information about this.

So, how can I migrate multilingual content?

**UPDATE:**
I found an example: https://github.com/drupal/drupal/tree/8.3.x/core/modules/migrate/tests/modules/migrate_external_translated_test

I was able for the moment to migrate the english content but not the translations.

Comment: *Disclaimer: I've never created a multi-lingual site before.* `I was able for the moment to migrate the english content` Here is my multilingual newbie Q/suggestion, Can't you just pretend you just created the D8 site in English and now you want to make it multilingual?

Comment: @NoSssweat I have a Multilingual site. I have in the CSV file the information in two languages and I need to create from this file the nodes in two languages (the node in english and his translation in french)

Comment: @NoSssweat can you post an answer with the steps to do it?

Comment: @NoSssweat text with format and text fields

Comment: Turns out I am way off, I hope [these 2 videos](https://buildamodule.com/video/upgrading-to-drupal-8-translation-workflow-changes-how-to-import-a-language-and-translate-the-interface-in-drupal-7-and-drupal-8) helps you

Comment: @NoSssweat why you delete your answer? I think that is interesting, can you post it again please?

Comment: Because it does not belong here, while interesting, it does not solve/answer this particular problem/question. I will bring it back soon in a new Q & A.

Comment: reposted [over here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224893/import-csv-to-nodes-entities-in-drupal-8-including-a-ui/224896#224896)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Migrate from CSV basics**

As stated elsewhere, the migration code has only recently (as of 8.2.x or 8.3.x) seemed to settle down and there are loads of old, outdated and incorrect instructions in blog posts around the web. That being said, I've had about 75% success following the instructions on these two sets of blog posts from Lucas Hedding and Ada Hernández at Mtech.

- https://www.mtech-llc.com/blog/lucas-hedding/migrating-using-csv
- https://www.mtech-llc.com/blog/ada-hernandez/how-migrate-images-drupal-8-using-csv-source

There is an accompanying example codebase Lucas setup at Github that covers the basics of the first CSV blog post example, but it doesn't include any helpers with the image or file migrations.

- https://github.com/heddn/d8_custom_migrate

There is another example repository from Wunderkraut that does include a CSV example migration with user, taxonomy, articles and images migration here:

- https://github.com/wunderkraut/migrate_source_example/tree/8.2.x/modules/migrate_source_example_csv

**Multilingual migration from CSV**

I recommend starting with the CSV basics above, then moving to this section. You really need to have separate migration scripts for each language.

I got an additional 20% of the way there with this blog post, that outlines the details how to modify a migration yaml file to support *multilingual content* including, to enable `translations: true` in the `destination` section, to add the the `langcode:` field in the `process` section for proper multi-lingual entities (like nodes and terms), and to add the `language:` parameter for specific multi-language field processing.

- https://blog.liip.ch/archive/2017/01/05/drupal-8-multilingual-content.html

I've found the most difficult part to be figuring out how to import file or image fields (the remaining 5% for me).  Neither of the examples above demonstrate how to import image alt fields properly. In my case I have an image field that shares the image, but the alt attribute is translatable. I figured out how to import the basic alt field to the default language node on my own, but I'm having trouble getting the import to use the same fid but different alt text for other languages. The solution was figured out by user @Vasi by adding an additional field called `content_translation_source` on the process step of the foreign language migration YAML. More details with complete example here:

- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/229874/3167

**Additional Discussion**

Finally, there is some discussion going on here as well:

- [#2733431: Multilingual Migrations for Non-Drupal Sources](https://www.drupal.org/node/2733431)

Comment: I've created a follow-up question for my remaining problem here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/229750/how-to-migrate-multilingual-image-alt-fields-from-csv

Comment: thanks, I will test the code with the info in your answer

Comment: Turns out the missing key here is to add a `content_translation_source` field on the `process` section of the foreign language translation, the value should be set to the language code of the original language imported. See Vasi's answer on the link above. I'll also update my post to reflect this fix.

Answer (score 3):

you need both migration-tasks, the yml files in the migration folder:

```
migrate.migration.external_translated_test_node.yml
migrate.migration.external_translated_test_node_translation.yml
```

Then in the Plugin (MigrateExternalTranslatedTestSource.php), you need to read your .csv (in `initializeIterator()`) into the structure of the import array:

```
  /**
   * The data to import.
   *
   * @var array
   */
   protected $import = [
    ['name' => 'cat', 'title' => 'Cat', 'lang' => 'English'],
    ['name' => 'cat', 'title' => 'Chat', 'lang' => 'French'],
    ['name' => 'cat', 'title' => 'Gato', 'lang' => 'Spanish'],
    ['name' => 'dog', 'title' => 'Dog', 'lang' => 'English'],
    ['name' => 'dog', 'title' => 'Chien', 'lang' => 'French'],
    ['name' => 'monkey', 'title' => 'Monkey', 'lang' => 'English'],
   ];
```