# Drupal 7 to drupal 8 Migration - field collection fields

Tags: 8, migrations, entities

I have been trying to migrate my Drupal 7 site to Drupal 8.25. I have more than 20 contents type, and all are using field_collection module.

I have successfully migrated to drupal8, but as field collection module not supported for migration, I am unable to make the movement successful. 
Is there any way to do it manually or any other solution?

Comment: `Is there any way to do it manually` check out [my answer here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224893/import-csv-to-nodes-entities-in-drupal-8-including-a-ui/224896#224896)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for quick response, Could it be able to migrate field collection too?

Comment: Yep. You just need to make a CSV file that contains all your field collection info. You could use [Views Data Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) to do that. Once you have it, you just need to alter my code so it targets the Field Collection ID's of the Fields. If your node's already exist. You will want to use my last code that starts with `Sub Drupal_Edit()`

Comment: Hi Thanks for your detailed information regarding the use of VBA, Excel, and Internet explorer. My question is how it will import all the contents along with images associated with the content type in drupal 7.

Comment: Use [FileField Sources](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) which will allow you to upload images by pasting an URL. Make URL the only or default option and then simply paste/insert url via VBA Excel and when you save the node, it uploads it. The D8 dev version works fine for me. Go to "Manage Form Display" and edit the image widget to enable it.

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply, I wanted to know, will I have to manually add all the contents one by one? In that case it will take ages

Comment: Use VBA excel...

Comment: Hi, @NoSssweat I have more than 30,000 contents to migrate, all with massive use of taxonomy terms and field collection. I am trying to use this method- https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/upgrade/using-the-migrate-source-csv-plugin, using uuid I may be possibly migrate. CanI do the same with your methodology?

Comment: WOW that's a lot of content. with my methodology it's doable, but it will take you like 3.4 days running it 24/7 assuming you do 6 nodes per minute.

Comment: PS: You might want to use [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) instead of [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) if you read the field collection page it says, `Paragraphs is likely to replace field collection for Drupal 8. Field collection is on its way to being deprecated.`

Comment: well yeah, I know field collection will be discontinued, but I think there is a no way to migrate to paragraph. My website is very big so I need to do something to make a swift migration. Also, I do have more than 100000 images. 12GB website. 
I

Comment: Hi I have found something that could help me, didn't check yet. I will confirm after trying -  https://www.drupal.org/node/2757989

Comment: That looks promising, if it works you can post it as an answer :)

Comment: I was able to get this working in a recent project. I detailed what I did here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2757989#comment-11824730. In short, you need to build a custom source plugin that breaks all the incoming field collection items into separate migration "rows".

Comment: @mikeker, drupal migration doesn't allow another migration. How can we perform second migration

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "drupal migration doesn't allow another migration"...  You can run as many migrations as needed, each one needs a separate migration yml file.

Comment: Hi @mikeker I meant thorough drupal migration UI you can perform only once as it's not allow us for second try.

Comment: Ahh... Sorry, I haven't used the UI module yet. You might consider running the migration(s) from Drush via the migrate_tools module (https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_tools).

Comment: @mikeker so through drush we can migrate as many times we want?

Comment: Yes. Import, test, rollback, re-import, update a previously run import with new data. Drush is definitely the way to go!

Comment: Hi @mikeker I wanted to know what is multi value field collection

Comment: Fields can be single value fields or multi-value fields (eg: /admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields/node.article.field_image/storage). A field collection is just a field that renders the collection instead of a single widget and can have a single or multiple entries.

Comment: Hi @mikeker, wanted to know how to find these entries while migrating FC 

`Host entity type
' public function fields() {
    $fields = array(
      'item_id' => $this->t('Item ID'),
      'revision_id' => $this->t('Revision ID'),
      'field_name' => $this->t('Name of field'),
      'entity_type' => $this->t('Host entity type'),
      'entity_id' => $this->t('Host entity ID'),
    ); `

Comment: I wanted to know what I should write for the host entity id, revision id and item id