# Migrate Paragraphs from CSV

Tags: i18n-l10n, migrations, paragraphs

I am migrating Paragraphs from CSV file. I have Paragraph called Text with two fields -> title and body.

The problem is that I would like to also migrate translations for them, which currently don't know how to achieve. Tried with the migration_lookup plugin and translations: true option, but receive error for duplicate primary key ids.

What is the way to do this?

Comment: Is this for Drupal 8?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be the [content import](https://www.drupal.org/project/contentimport) module that allows you to import among other things paragraph content from CSV I believe and you can specify language for each field.  Give it a try

Comment: Sadly, not yet, see issue "Add support for importing Paragraphs references" at https://www.drupal.org/project/contentimport/issues/3001880

Answer (score 0):

You will need two migrations. One for the paragraphs in the default language and one for the translations. Make sure the migration for the translation include the language code as a key.

And this post looks useful, https://evolvingweb.ca/blog/migrate-translations-csv-json-or-xml-drupal-8. As do all the links here, 
 [How to migrate multilingual content from CSV to Drupal 8?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224099/how-to-migrate-multilingual-content-from-csv-to-drupal-8)

Comment: I tried that approach, but the problem is that the migration doesn't create translation for the default language, but creates new paragraph records.